# add kubernetes worker node with ansible but it doesn't get join

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubectl

I'm trying to stablish a kubernetes system and I'm using ansible.
and these are my playbooks:

**hosts**:

```
[masters]
 master ansible_host=157.90.96.140 ansible_user=root

[workers]
 worker1 ansible_host=157.90.96.138 ansible_user=root
 worker2 ansible_host=157.90.96.139 ansible_user=root


[all:vars]
 ansible_user=ubuntu
 ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
 kubelet_cgroup_driver=cgroupfs
 ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

**initial**

```
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: create the 'ubuntu' user
      user: name=ubuntu append=yes state=present createhome=yes shell=/bin/bash

    - name: allow 'ubuntu' to have passwordless sudo
      lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/sudoers
        line: 'ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'
        validate: 'visudo -cf %s'

    - name: set up authorized keys for the ubuntu user
      authorized_key: user=ubuntu key="{{item}}"
      with_file:
        - ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

**kube-dependencies**

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
   - name: install Docker
     apt:
       name: docker.io
       state: present
       update_cache: true

   - name: install APT Transport HTTPS
     apt:
       name: apt-transport-https
       state: present

   - name: add Kubernetes apt-key
     apt_key:
       url: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
       state: present

   - name: add Kubernetes' APT repository
     apt_repository:
      repo: deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
      state: present
      filename: 'kubernetes'

   - name: install kubernetes-cni
     apt:
         name: kubernetes-cni=0.7.5-00
         state: present
         force: yes
         update_cache: true

   - name: install kubelet
     apt:
       name: kubelet=1.14.0-00
       state: present
       update_cache: true

   - name: install kubeadm
     apt:
       name: kubeadm=1.14.0-00
       state: present

- hosts: master
  become: yes
  tasks:
   - name: install kubectl
     apt:
       name: kubectl=1.14.0-00
       state: present
       force: yes
```

**master**

```
- hosts: master
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: initialize the cluster
      shell: kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 >> cluster_initialized.txt
      args:
        chdir: $HOME
        creates: cluster_initialized.txt

    - name: create .kube directory
      become: yes
      become_user: ubuntu
      file:
        path: $HOME/.kube
        state: directory
        mode: 0755

    - name: copy admin.conf to user's kube config
      copy:
        src: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
        dest: /home/ubuntu/.kube/config
        remote_src: yes
        owner: ubuntu

    - name: install Pod network
      become: yes
      become_user: ubuntu
      shell: kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/a70459be0084506e4ec919aa1c114638878db11b/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml >> pod_network_setup.txt
      args:
        chdir: $HOME
        creates: pod_network_setup.txt
```

**worker**

```
- hosts: master
  become: yes
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: get join command
      shell: kubeadm token create --print-join-command
      register: join_command_raw

    - name: set join command
      set_fact:
        join_command: "{{ join_command_raw.stdout_lines[0] }}"

- hosts: workers
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: join cluster
      shell: "{{ hostvars['master'].join_command }} >> node_joined.txt"
      args:
        chdir: $HOME
        creates: node_joined.txt
```

my manual for installation was

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-ansible-on-ubuntu-16-04

**now I have several question:**

1. Are these configs right?

2.In master playbook I'm using manual pod network and I didn't change it is that correct?

3. my main problem is my workers don't get join what's the problem?

Comment: I have run your playbooks and they seem to work correctly (workers node has joined the cluster).
What do you mean by: `my workers don't get join` ?
Do you have any errors while running playbooks ?
If you want to install Kubernetes using Ansible, you can use [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray).

Comment: my workers node has not join and when I run  `kubectl get node` it shows only master node. I don't get any errors

Comment: What do you have in the `node_joined.txt` file ?